# Moser Iteration for Laplacian with Hardy potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I am reading the following proof of [Cao-Yan's 2010 CVPDE Paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-009-0295-5). It's a property for solutions of Laplace equation with Hardy potential $|x|^{-2}.$ The space dimension $N \geq 3.$ Their proof is in the following 5 pictures.

**Question:** how do the authors get (A.25) (in the last picture)? ***That is, how can they get rid of the term $\|w\|_{L^p(B_R(y))}$ in the RHS of (A.24)?***

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]